# Resultado decimal se almacena como 0 en dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, float

Ejecuto un calculo para identificar la distancia entre dos coordenadas, este da un valor decimal pero al guardarlo en el dataframe, queda como 0, que estoy omitiendo? por ejemplo, el valor 0.0563492, queda como 0

```
for i in range(len(result_trabajos_hidro)):   
    distancia=haversine(result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LATITUD'],result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LONGITUD'],result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LATITUD_REPOR_MUNI'],result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LONGITUD_REPOR_MUNI'])
    result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['DISTANCIA']=distancia
    print(round(distancia,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás estés guardando el tipo de dato como `int` intenta guardarlo como `float` así:

```
for i in range(len(result_trabajos_hidro)):   
    distancia=haversine(result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LATITUD'].astype('float64'),result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LONGITUD'].astype('float64'),result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LATITUD_REPOR_MUNI'].astype('float64'),result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['LONGITUD_REPOR_MUNI'].astype('float64'))
    result_trabajos_hid.iloc[i]['DISTANCIA']=distancia
    print(round(distancia,3))
```

### Nota:

Si la solución no es la correcta por favor edita tu pregunta y deja un fragmento de tu `dataframe` para verificar con que tipo de dato estás trabajando puedes utilizar la función `.dtype`